# AJAX javascript firstChild.data returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am creating a very simple messaging system. I am stuck on a point where AJAX gathers information from PHP file. PHP gets messages data from the database and outputs the data gathered from the database embedded with some HTML tags like:

```
echo "<li class='cm'><b>".ucwords($name)."</b> - ".$message."</li>";
```

, in order to append them inside a div tag to display the message. I cannot figure out why

```
var code = xmlDocumentelement.firstChild.data;
```

on line 46 in JavaScript returns undefined where it should execute the whole PHP code where it does, but it doesn't want to return the HTML tag code outputed with echo (showed above) for some reason. I figure out that the error might be in JavaScript where I have to do something else (around line 46) to get the HTML code generated by PHP. So, PHP, SQL and HTML are 100% ok. ALL codes are below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chatRoom.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="process()">
        <div class="chatContainer">
            <div class="chatHeader">
                <h3>Welcome <?php echo ucwords($user); ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="chatMessages" id="chatMessages"></div>
            <div class="chatBottom">
                <form action="getMessages.php" onSubmit="return false;" id="chatForm">
                    <input type="hidden" id="name" value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
                    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="" placeholder="type your chat message"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject){ //IE 6,7
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    else{
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("can't create object");
    }
    else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

function process(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4){ 
        xmlHttp.open("GET","http://localhost/chat%20system/getMessages.php",true); //preparing the request. the last parameter is asynchronous meaning if your wan't to make the preperation asynchronously.
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else{
        setTimeout("process()", 500);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
            var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            var xmlDocumentelement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            var code = xmlDocumentelement.firstChild.data;

            document.getElementById("chatMessages").innerHTML = code ;
            //the code above wont work if the function where getElementsByClassNames.
            setTimeout("process()", 1000);
        }
        else{
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("something went wrong");
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST'); 

include "db.php";

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';

// get messages
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//Fetch
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $message = $fetch['message'];

    echo "<li class='cm'><b>".ucwords($name)."</b> - ".$message."</li>";
}

echo '</response>';

?>
```

This is all the code that I have used. Please let me know if you need extra info as I have explained the problem.

Comment: What is the value of xmlDocumentelement?

Comment: Why would you think there is a `data` property on the `firstChild`? If you are wanting to add that html to your element just use `yourElement.appendChild( xmlDocumentelement.firstChild )`

Comment: patric evans, I added it and it just appends the name and the message once without the list item tag and it appends it . What I want to do is to append all the messages stored into the database at once and overwrite the elements inside that div element every time when I get data from PHP (that's why I have the while loop).

Comment: @mulquin       is [object HTMLCollection]